# TypeError: 'Connection' object is not iterable when I try to get data from MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, database, typeerror

I get

> `TypeError: 'Connection' object is not iterable`

when I try to take data from my MySQL DB.

I want to take random 5 data from my DB and initialize with something. Than ı want to send this data with e-mail. My first problem is, I can't take a any value from my DB.

Here is my code, ı need help.

```
import MySQLdb
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from random import randint
import mysql.connector


db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", port=3308,
                     user="root", passwd="", db="mail_project")
cur = db.cursor()

cur.execute("""
    SELECT * FROM 
        `mail_project`.`words`
    WHERE ID = 5;
""", db)
db.commit()
```

Comment: Dont put the db into `cur.execute`, just your query is ok

Comment: I can't see any output. What should I print after the `db.commit()` line ?

Comment: you need to get the output from cur, `records = cursor.fetchall()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try executing without adding the db connection at the end.

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM mail_project.words WHERE ID = 5")
```

- Also it is a select query which means there is no need to commit any changes.
- both pymysql or MySQLdb support only 1 query at a time, so need of semi-colon as well.

You can fetch your results by using cur.fetchall() or cur.fetchone()

try using

```
print(cur.fetchall())
```

- If it is one line, It will give your results inside a tuple format.
- More than one would give your results as tuple inside a tuple format.

Also, In DB using try and except block is always good practice, Since anything can happen if it is not an on-prem server.